# Fill table with data from knockout js observableArray then take one item from the list and display it in the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Good day
I am new to knockout js and what is described in the title is what I am trying to do. The first part I can do but I just cant figure out how to put values into form here is some code. 
With this I get the data:

```
$.ajax('@Url.Action("GetEducations", "Candidate")', {
        data: { id: @ViewBag.CandidateId },
        type: "post", dataType: 'json'
    })
        .done(function (result) {
            var mappedEducations = $.map(result, function (item) { return new Education(item) });
            self.educations(mappedEducations);
        })
    .fail(function (xhr, status) {
        alert('@Resources.WebAppLocalization.general_Error');
    });
```

Here I put them into table:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: educations, visible: educations().length > 0">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: InstitutionName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Qualification"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: EducationFrom"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: EducationTill"></td>
        <td>
            <a class="link" data-bind="attr: {href: ''}, click: $parent.editEducationFill, clickBubble: false"></a>               
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now when someone click's on edit link it goes here:

```
 self.editEducationFill = function (education) {
     //TODO
    }
```

From here I want the passed object to go to edit form here:

```
<form id="FormID">
  <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: InstitutionName"/> </div>
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: Qualification" /></div>
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: EducationFrom" /></div>
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: EducationTill" /></div>
</form>
```

However I just cant get it to work.
For any help thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an observable to your view model that will hold the education object you want to edit.

```
self.educationToEdit = ko.observable();
```

In your method: self.editEducationToFill, set the educationToEdit to the one that's passed into the method.

```
self.editEducationFill = function(education){
    self.educationToEdit(education);
}
```

In your view, add a data-binding that tells the form to use the educationToFill observable to display on your page.

```
<form id="FormID" data-bind="with: educationToEdit">
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: InstitutionName"/></div>
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: Qualification" /></div>
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: EducationFrom" /></div>
    <div class="detValue"><input type="text" data-bind="value: EducationTill" /></div>
</form>
```